# NodeJS Connect Middleware Function Setup

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to understand how Middleware works and specifically the Connect module for NodeJS.  I was going through this http://howtonode.org/connect-it and found this example:

```
module.exports = function logItSetup() {

  // Initialize the counter
  var counter = 0;

  return function logItHandle(req, res, next) {
    var writeHead = res.writeHead; // Store the original function

    counter++;

    // Log the incoming request
    console.log("Request " + counter + " " + req.method + " " + req.url);

    // Wrap writeHead to hook into the exit path through the layers.
    res.writeHead = function (code, headers) {
      res.writeHead = writeHead; // Put the original back

      // Log the outgoing response
      console.log("Response " + counter + " " + code + " " + JSON.stringify(headers));

      res.writeHead(code, headers); // Call the original
    };

    // Pass through to the next layer
    next();
  };
};
```

So I know it logs the incoming request and response.  But even with the below explanation from the article, I still don't understand you need to replace the writeHead with a replacement function:

"The setup function is a great place to setup variables used by the middleware across requests. In this case we're initializing the counter for the logger.

In the handler we are using a wrapping idiom to hook into the call to writeHead. In JavaScript functions are values just like anything else. So a great way to wrap functions is to store a reference to the original implementation in a closure variable. Replace the function with a new one, and in the first line of the new function, put the old function definition back. Then on the last line of the replacement function call the original. This is a simple and efficient way to hook into existing object methods since they just look for properties by name and not references to actual function objects.

The standalone console.log call will be called at the beginning of each request cycle, and the nested console.log will be called on the way out by means of the nested writeHead function."

Answer (score 1):

Every time there's an incoming request, it goes through the stack middleware. These are simple functions that take 3 params `req`,`res`,`next` and are kinda like this:

```
function someMiddleware(req,res,next){
  // do stuff with request & response...

  // You need to call next to keep going through the stack
  next(); 
}
```

In your example, you can use the module like this:

```
connect()
.use(function(req,res,next){
  //some other handler
  // ...
  // Call next
  next();
})
.use(logInSetup) //Assuming you named it like this
```

The module `returns` a function that is exactly what that stack middleware is expecting. This is [how connects does it](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/logger.html)... It's basically the same idea.

The `writeHead` function is stored in a variable so you can call `console.log` on every request and then call the actual function. Take into account that `writeHead` will not be called when this function is called but when `res.writeHead` is called from somewhere else.
It's a (very clever) way of modifying a function without altering it's original implementation.

A very simple example:

```
//Assume this function is a dependency and cannot be alter
function sumNums(a,b){
  return a + b;
}

var sumNums_copy = sumNums;

function sumNums(a,b) {
  console.log('Log and the sum');
  sumNums_copy(a,b);
};

sumNums_copy(2,2); // sums
sumNums(2,2); // sums and logs
```

Functions are first class objects in javascript meaning that they can passed as parameters to other functions, returnedfrom functions, or stored in variables.